# PHP Prophecy ->reveal() method - should I put the expectations (like "willReturn", "ShouldBeCalled") before or after it?

Tags: php, testing, prophecy

Working with PHP Prophecy now. I have two codes samples:
One:

```
$aProphecy = $this->prophesize(A::class);
$aProphecy->someMethod()->willReturn([]);
//now can be used:
$aProphecy->reveal();
```

Two

```
$aProphecy = $this->prophesize(A::class);
$aProphecy->reveal();
$aProphecy->someMethod()->willReturn([]);
```

I can't understand which is the correct way, and why?

Answer (score 0):

The order of your examples is not relevant at this point because both cases will be evaluated.
However, I prefer the first variant, because it is clearer what is expected from $aProphecy.

The important thing to notice is that your code isn't checking anything as you need to inject $aProphecy to another object and reveal it there:

```
$aProphecy = $this->prophesize(A::class);
$aProphecy->someMethod()->willReturn([]);
$bObject = new B($aProphecy->reveal());
$bObject->methodWhichCallSomeMethodInside();
// check if someMethod was called exactly once
$aProchecy->someMethod()->shouldBeCalled();
```